# Angular UI.Bootstrap's radio buttons act strange with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem dynamically generating options for a radio model in angular's ui.bootstrap. I thought I could simply ng-repeat over an array, using it's contents for the btn-radio attribute like so:

```
//in the controller
$scope.radioModel =  undefined;
$scope.radioModelButtons = ["a", "b", "c"];

//in the html
<div class="btn-group" >
  <button ng-repeat="value in radioModelButtons"
    class="btn" type="button" ng-model="radioModel"
    btn-radio="'{{value}}'">
      {{value}}
  </button>
</div>
```

I'm using angular 1.1.4 and ui.bootstrap 0.3.0.

[Here is a jsfiddle of my efforts](http://jsfiddle.net/yMLqz/), as you can see, the radio buttons act independently and do not affect the radioModel variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is how you should write your markup:

```
<button ng-repeat="value in radioModelButtons"
        class="btn" type="button" ng-model="radio.model"
        btn-radio="value">
          {{value}}
</button>
```

And the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMLqz/2/

There were 2 problems in your approach:

- `btn-radio` should be used with AngularJS expression, and not an interpolated value
- `ng-repeat` is creating a new scope so you need to take this into account if you want to bind to a value defined on a parent scope

Comment: Thanks a lot :D I am now reading "The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance"